# How can I align the next lines in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, string-formatting

I can't figure out how to right align these columns in JAVA. I tried several ways but none of them work. It works for other characters but not for Chinese.

```
String line1="冻结金额";
String line2="投资中金额";
String line3="投资中金额额";
String line4="投资中金中金额";
System.out.format("%-10s %s %n",line1, "XX" );
System.out.format("%-10s %s %n",line2, "XX" );
System.out.format("%-10s %s %n",line3, "XX" );
System.out.format("%-10s %s %n",line4, "XX" );
```

This is the expected result but even here it is not displayed correctly

```
冻结金额             XX 
投资中金额           XX
投资中金额额         XX
投资中金中金额       XX
```

Comment: Please make an example on how you wan't the output to be!

Comment: Obviously right aligned. It's a 10 character width column with right aligment.

Answer (score 3):

You could (ab-)use the [*tai tou*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_tou), full width space, `"\u3000"`:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %s",line1, "XX").replace(" ", "\u3000"));
```

Though with litte effort, you could do HTML output.

Comment: Although with this solution, strings with non-Chinese characters won't format correctly. There probably isn't a solution that works for both.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the Java code, only the way the output is displayed.

The output is as follows:

```
冻结金额       XX 
投资中金额      XX 
投资中金额额     XX 
投资中金中金额    XX
```

If you were actually to count the number of characters or do:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %s ",line1, "XX").length());
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %s ",line2, "XX").length());
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %s ",line3, "XX").length());
System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %s ",line4, "XX").length());
```

You'd see that each line has the same length (14).

The problem is that the display font doesn't show Chinese characters as the same size as other characters.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method, however I have no idea how it will work with Chinese characters:

```
public String padRight(String s, int n) 
{
    return String.format("%1$-" + n + "s", s);  
}
```

Call it like so: `padRight(StringToBePaddedToTheRight, intNumberOfPadsToTheRight);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys

You are right, nothing wrong with the code only the editor configuration.

In my case I am using eclipse editor, I just change the default font for an Unicode.

```
冻结金额　　　　　　　XX
投资中金额　　　　　　XX
投资中金额额　　　　　XX
```